# How to include multiple domains in an spf TXT Record ~all and ?all

Tags: domain, spf, txt-record

I am looking to setup a TXT spf record that has 2 included domains...individually:

```
v=spf1 include:hotmail.com ~all
```

and

```
v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net ?all
```

What is the proper way of combining them into a single item?

Comment: How do you want unhandled email to be treated?

Answer (score 4):

## Background information

### How include works

The [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.2) says this about include:

> The "include" mechanism triggers a recursive evaluation of
> check_host().

> 1. The <domain-spec> is expanded as per Section 7.

> 2. check_host() is evaluated with the resulting string as the
>    <domain>.  The <ip> and <sender> arguments remain the same as in
>    the current evaluation of check_host().

> 3. The recursive evaluation returns match, not-match, or an error.

> 4. If it returns match, then the appropriate result for the
>    "include" mechanism is used (e.g., include or +include produces a
>    "pass" result and -include produces "fail").

> 5. If it returns not-match or an error, the parent check_host()
>    resumes processing as per the table below, with the previous
>    value of <domain> restored.

### Mechanisms (the default mechanism is pass)

#### "+" pass

> A "pass" result means the client is authorized to inject mail with
> the given identity.  The domain can now, in the sense of reputation,
> be considered responsible for sending the message.  Further policy
> checks can now proceed with confidence in the legitimate use of the
> identity.  This is further discussed in Appendix G.1.

#### "-" fail

> A "fail" result is an explicit statement that the client is not
> authorized to use the domain in the given identity.  Disposition of
> SPF fail messages is a matter of local policy.  See Appendix G.2 for
> considerations on developing local policy.

#### "~" softfail

> A "softfail" result ought to be treated as somewhere between "fail"
> and "neutral"/"none".  The ADMD believes the host is not authorized
> but is not willing to make a strong policy statement.  Receiving
> software SHOULD NOT reject the message based solely on this result,
> but MAY subject the message to closer scrutiny than normal.

#### "?" neutral

> A "neutral" result indicates that although a policy for the identity
> was discovered, there is no definite assertion (positive or negative)
> about the client.

> A "neutral" result MUST be treated exactly like the "none" result;
> the distinction exists only for informational purposes.  Treating
> "neutral" more harshly than "none" would discourage ADMDs from
> testing the use of SPF records (see Section 10.1).

## Provided SPF records explained

### `v=spf1 include:hotmail.com ~all`

- If the email passes `hotmail.com` then pass it, otherwise treat it as suspicious.

### `v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net ?all`

- If the email passes `servers.mcsv.net` then pass it, otherwise treat is as if there was no SPF record.

## How to merge them

If you want unmatched emails to be treated as neutral, use:

```
v=spf1 include:hotmail.com include:servers.mcsv.net ?all
```

If you want it to be treated as being suspicious, then use:

```
v=spf1 include:hotmail.com include:servers.mcsv.net ~all
```

## Explaining SPF records

I have made a site (https://www.checkspf.net/), which allows you to see an SPF record explained, with each individual part of the record explained. It is a work in progress site though, so there may be some issues, I am open to Pull Requests with fixes or issue reports.

Comment: Great answer, helps a lot not only to include two domains, but understand how it works.